# "Do you know where Eiffel Tower is?" or "Do you know where is Eiffel Tower?"

Tags: word-order, relative-clauses

Can we swap the word order in these two sentences to get the same meaning:

> 1)Do you know where Eiffel Tower is?

> 2)Do you know where is Eiffel Tower?

Similarly can we swap the words in this sentence:

> 1)Do you know where is Anna?

> 2)Do you know where Anna is?

Comment: Your first sentence requires the definite article **the** before "Eiffel Tower."

Answer (score 2):

In a direct question (if the question word isn't the subject), we invert the verb or auxiliary and the subject:

> Where is the Eiffel Tower?

In an indirect (or embedded) question, we do not:

> Do you know where the Eiffel tower is?

So your 1) in the first pair and 2) in the second are idiomatic (once you insert the article, as randomhead says). The other two are not.